# Configure SQL Server listening port with Ansible

Tags: sql-server, ansible, chocolatey

I installed SQL Server Express Edition in remote Windows machine using Ansible-playbook, Ansible module "win_chocolatey" and Chocolatey package "sql-server-express". Here is my Ansible-playbook task:

```
- name: "Install SQL Server Express Edition"
  win_chocolatey:
    name: sql-server-express
    state: present
```

How to make that installed SQL Server instance listening on port 1433?

Comment: Perhaps your problem is firewall settings? First determine the real problem, then search the way to fix it with Ansible.

Comment: I can connect via RDP to remote machine and check, that SQL server is installed via "choco list -l" command. And via TCPView I see, that SQL server is not listening at any port. Although in list of services I see, that SQL server is running. So, the problem is not in firewall.

Comment: But probably you must allow TCP 1433 port on that computer's firewall?